# Is it possible to repackage an APK

Tags: android, apk

Out of curiosity, is it possible to repackage an [APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package)?

For example: I will install my APK, change a few settings, download additional items within the app and then repackage the APK. So, when I install on other devices, its pre-configured and ready to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depending on what you want to do with it. An APK is just a zip file. You'll need to resign it when done, and it wouldn't reinstall on top of an old version (you'd need to uninstall and reinstall as you won't have the same key). But I've worked at places where we built a generic APK, then loaded [OEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_equipment_manufacturer) specific images/settings before generating the final version.